# After chmod can't login on VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, azure

Change permissions on file /etc/passwd on 640, then chmod o-r .
After that, i can't login on server on ssh.
Putty says "Network error: Software caused connection abort".

What problems? And how i can fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What problems?  Basically, you broke it.

If you have console access, boot from a rescue image - and change the permissions on `/etc/passwd` back to what they're supposed to be.

Comment: But what wrong in 640 /etc/passwd?

Comment: @PhilippCrux Most likely the login process can't read the file to determine if the account you're trying to log in with exists.

Comment: It's weird, i think. 
All users can see /etc/passwd - it is not secure..

Comment: @PhilippCrux What's not secure about it?  Account names aren't secret.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to read /etc/passwd. It's for user information. Passwords are stored in /etc/shadow.